# How to stop an app from being launched in BREW MP

Tags: applet, brew-framework, brewmp

I am new to BREW MP platform so i don't know that much as u guys know about it. I need your suggestion in figuring out an issue.

I want to make an app which always run in a background (I have found that it is possible in BREW). I want my app to stop particular app from being launched, i.e when user try to start a new application on device my background app show a message that you cannot run this application . May be i will contain a list of apps name which are allowed to run.

So my queries are,

1) How can i detect a blacklist app or the app which is not in my list? can i do this by app
name ? or it will need some thing else

2) Can i stop an app from being launched?

I will be really thankful if some one even give me a little bit of help in sorting this out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you can maybe do this, but that your app will not pass testing.

Answer (score 1):

When you develop a Brew Application, you will get a class ID (BID). You can know your class id, but how will you know the BID of other apps which are not your own? I am not sure that it will be accepted for when you submit it to True_Brew_Testing.